# Android - How to query in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Basically I have to listen a object. Please see the attached images.

[Memo List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYgEt.png)

[Memo Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxLlc.png)

So I need to get all `memos` which equal to `hash_tag = "love"`. How to overcome this problem?

```
Query query = memo.child(Memo.HASH_TAG).startAt("love");
query.addChildEventListener(mMemoChildEventListener);
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can check  some basics guides for retrieving data  here https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Answer (score 1):

### Android - How to query in firebase

```
MemoObject memoobject=new MemoObject();
  ArrayList<MemoObject> memoobjectArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
     DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query query = reference.child(Memo).orderByChild("hash_tag").equalTo("love");
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                   for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshots :dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                       memoobject=dataSnapshots.getValue(MemoObject.class);
             for(int i=0;i<memoobject.getHashTag().size();i++){
                  if(memoobject.getHashTag().get(i).equals("love"){
                    memoobjectArrayList.add(memoobject);
}
}
                        }
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```